# Example of wall-crossing formulae?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In a nutshell my question is "Are there any easy, educational wall-crossing formulae?".

Recently I often hear the word "(Kontsevich-Soibelman's etc) wall-crossing formula" in algebraic geometry talks. I wonder what they are like but am not really ready to read those relevant papers with high technology. I understand that this kind of formula expresses how your invariants of moduli spaces varies when you change the stability condition to construct the moduli spaces. Could someone provide me with a toy example? I am looking for a "wall-crossing formula" which can be understood by those with basic AG and maybe some GIT.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If "wall-corssing" is really "wall-crossing", then you might have a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/50992/wall-crossing-in-physics-and-mathematics 

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo. I am aware of the other post but I am interested in explicit computations rather than philosophical ideas. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I can tell you  the gist of a  "wall crossing formula".    Typically you have a  *space of parameters* $\newcommand{\eS}{\mathscr{S}}$ $\Lambda$,  a *configuration space*   $\newcommand{\eC}{\mathscr{C}}$ $\eC$, and a *parametrized moduli space* $\newcommand{\eM}{\mathscr{M}}$ $\eM$ which is a  subvariety $\eM\subset \eC\times \Lambda$.

We have a natural projection

$$\pi:\eM\to \Lambda. $$

The fiber of this map over $\lambda\in\Lambda$, denoted by $\eM_\lambda$,  is called *the moduli space corresponding to the  parameter $\lambda$*.

One could associate to $\eM_\lambda$ various invariants. For example, there might exists a sheaf $\eS\to\eM$ which restricts to a  sheaf $\eS_\lambda\to\eM_\lambda$. We denote   by  $e(\lambda)$ the Euler characteristic  of $H^\bullet(\eM_\lambda,\eS_\lambda)$.

It could happend that  $e(\lambda)$ depends on $\lambda$, but it could depend in a rather  specal way. Namely, there could exists  *real* codimension one  subvarieties  $W_i\subset \Lambda$, $i\in I$, called *walls*,  so that, if

$$ W:=\bigcup_{i\in I} W_i, $$

then $\lambda\to e(\lambda)$ is continuous on $\Lambda^\ast:=\Lambda\setminus W$.  In particular, the  function $\lambda\to e(\lambda)$ is constant on the connected components   of $\Lambda^*$, which are called *chambers*.

If    two chambers $C_0, C_1$ are adjacent, i.e.,  they sit on opposite sides of a wall  $W_i$ ,   then  $e(\lambda)$  has constant values $e(C_0)$ and $e(C_1)$ in these two chambers and a *wall crossing formula*  will tell you what the difference  $e(C_1)-e(C_0)$ is.

Here is a  trivial example.    Let $\Lambda=\mathbb{R}^2$.  We let $(b,c)$ denote the coordinates  of a point in $\Lambda$.   The configuration space $\eC$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and the parametrized moduli space is

$$\eM= \bigl\lbrace (t,b, c)\in\eC \times \Lambda;\;\;t^2+bt+c=0\,\bigr\rbrace. $$

The moduli space $\eM_{b,c}$ can be identified with the set of real roots of the quadratic polynomial $t^2+bt+c$. We denote by $e(b,c)$ the number of such roots. In other words, $e(b,c)$ is the (topological) Euler characteristic of the space $\eM_{b,c}$.

In this case we have a single  wall

$$ W=\bigl\lbrace (b,c)\in \Lambda;\;\; b^2- 4c=0\bigr\rbrace, $$

with two chambers,

$$ C^\pm=\bigl\lbrace \;\pm(b^2-4c)>0\;\bigr\rbrace. $$

In this case the Wall crossing formula is

$$ e(C^+)-e(C^-)= 2. $$

Comment: A simple but very nice example!! Thank you, Liviu!!

Comment: Liviu, I beg you pardon, it seems to me that the example you proposed tells us more or less how to solve quadratic equations with real coefficients. You can call this wall-crossing, but this sounds a little bit like giving a new name to a relatively old thing. For me this does not quite answer the question asked by Kim... I suspect that Kontsevich and Soibelman made some  more substantial progress? (though I might be wrong...)

Comment: The point of the concrete example is obviously *not* the final formula. It's the *explicit* description of the set-up. It is based on three pilars that appear in all situations: *the configuration space*, *the parameter space*, and *the parametrized  moduli space*. In the applications I am familiar with  (gauge theory)  *all of them* are infinite dimensional. However the fibers of $\pi$ are  finite dimensional. The  20th century terminology for the wall crossing formula was *bifurcation theory*.